# Solder joints advice

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, electrical

Do you think these power distribution joints would suffice or should I improve on them?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a well done soldering work. As long as the wires won't getting loose by casual pulling/twisting, it should stay for a long while.

Comment: hard to be 100% sure. when you soldered it, did you see it get hot enough to wick down to the pad? (the shininess changes at that moment, and there is a momentary flow along the surface of the bubble that was already melted... it's almost like a subtle phase transition). Anyway, if you immobilize the wires it should be okay, but "high quality" would involve a little practice and having caught the failures a few times

Comment: "should I improve on them" ... probably not, if it works. too much rework can damage

Comment: I showed a few people and they said I may have added a little too much solder and they may be correct. I also did have some issue with spreading the solder solidly on the power distribution board solder pads just had to hold it a little while longer.

Comment: Are the wires going through the through-holes in the pads and soldered on the other side as well? Or have you just stuck them on one side which risks the pads being pulled off?

Comment: Definitely place it in such a way the wires won't be putting stress on the board. The solder joints look fine, but with wires this thick it's just asking for peeling the paths apart from the board by having one of the wires accidentally knocked hard, bent or pulled. Electrically it's fine, but mechanically it's a disaster waiting to happen if not properly protected.

Comment: You appear to come from the "the bigger the blob, the better the job" school of soldering :) Those wires need to be carefully clamped or bogged to the same frame as the board. There needs to be no load whatsoever on the wires at the solder joints. Solder is both weak and brittle. The less the better.

Answer (score 0):

The surfaces of the solder joints are shiny and smooth. A cold solder job would result in a less-shiny surface. Movement during cooling would create a granular-appearing surface (known from experience) and would be considered unreliable.

There's indication in the image of smooth flow to the vias on the board, which means a good temperature and a solid bond. If the contacts are flat on the board, you've done a good job. If the contacts are pass-throughs and the underside has the same shiny appearance, you've done a good job.

The insulation appears undamaged as well. That means you've used correct heating and/or it is silicone high-temperature insulation, all good indicators.

There are no visible bridges which would result in a short circuit.

nicely done.

Comment: Thanks for the tips to look out for a soldering job. One concern I have is the material around the solder pads on my power distribution board seem a little rough. Do you know how I can go about cleaning those. I have heard isopropyl alcohol is a possibility would you recommend?

Comment: If you have "sloppy" flux hanging about, IPA is a good safe solvent.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but it should function fine. People talk a lot about cold solder joints but in my opinion the most important aspect of a good solder joint is both parts being fully wetted with solder. It looks like you accomplished that.

This isn't bad considering those high power pads with thick gauge wires can be a nightmare to solder.

For future reference, I believe your iron wattage is too low. The pads and wire are wicking away heat faster than the iron can add it, so you joint never melts completely and gets all bulky like you're seeing. If your iron has an adjustable temperature you may be able to compensate somewhat by turning it up a little bit, but really you just need a more powerful iron; like 60 - 100 watts and temperature controlled.

Comment: I find iron tip size is more important than wattage. I'd rather solder that with a 40 watt iron with a 6mm chisel tip than with a 100W iron with a 1mm chisel tip.